# Angular 2: *ngIf, Template parse errors, {{}} works well

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular version 2.4.1 and I have error 'Template parse errors:(…)' when I'm running this code:
Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedData} from '../student/student.data';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'sd-toolbar',
    templateUrl: 'toolbar.component.html',
    providers: [SharedData]
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
    var: boolean;
    var2: number;
    constructor(service: SharedData){
        this.var = service.getLog();
        this.var2 = service.getId();
        console.log(this.var);
    }
}
```

Module code:

```
import {NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ToolbarComponent} from './toolbar.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ ToolbarComponent ],
})
class MyComponentModule {}
```

and Html code:

```
<nav class="site-menu">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div *ngIf="!var">
        <div class="notifications">
            <a class="notifications__toggle" data-toggle="notifications" href="#notifications">
                <span class="num">4</span>
            </a>
            <div class="notifications__list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="view.html#msgs-1">Ny notifikation på 287530</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

{{var2}} in html shows good, but it's problem with that *ngIf, can you guys help me with this problem?

Comment: is it working if you remove the `ngIf`

Comment: var is reserved word in Javascript. Could you please try some other variable name

Comment: @XAVI thanks a lot, stupid mistake, problem solved :)